# Is psychology relevant to whether the fulfilment of an unlikely prediction is evidence that the predicter had some sort of foreknowledge?

Tags: psychology, evidence, prediction

When someone makes a prediction that is very unlikely to come true, then if the prediction is fulfilled then we **generally** have strong reason to think that he had some prior knowledge or information which allowed him to make an accurate prediction or that he somehow influenced the events to make his prediction come true.

It has been claimed to me that the psychology of the person making the prediction plays no role in determining whether the fulfilment of the prediction is evidence that the predicter had access to information which allowed him to make an accurate prediction or influenced the events to make his prediction come true.

However, it seems to me that sometimes psychology does play role in determining whether the fulfilment of the prediction is evidence that the predicter had access to information which allowed him to make an accurate prediction or influenced the events to make his prediction come true. In particular, when we would expect the prediction to be made by the predictor despite its unlikelihood, the fulfilment of the prediction seems to offer no significant evidence in favour of the predicter having some sort of foreknowledge (be it information we couldn’t access, some other source of knowledge or the ability to influence the relevant future events).

Take the following examples:

1. Suppose someone buys a lottery ticket, then predicts that he will win the lottery and late does win the lottery. I don’t think that the fulfilment of the prediction is evidence for any foreknowledge, superior information or tampering with the lottery in this case, since it is natural for anyone to predict that they will win. Perhaps they will predict it as a joke, perhaps they will predict it from wishful thinking, etc. etc.. Either way, the fulfilment of the prediction, despite the incredible unlikelihood of the prediction being fulfilled, does not seem to be significant evidence that this person somehow knew that he would win the lottery.
2. Suppose a very small, weak country went to war with a very large, strong country. Suppose further that a general in the army of the small, weak country predicts that his country will win the war. If his country does somehow win the war, then regardless of the unlikelihood of this happening, I don’t think that the fulfilment of the prediction is evidence that the general somehow knew that his country would win the war. Perhaps he made the prediction out of patriotism, perhaps he made the prediction out of wishful thinking, perhaps he made the prediction to boost his troops’ morale, etc. etc.. Either way, the fulfilment of the prediction, despite the very great unlikelihood of the prediction being fulfilled, does not seem to be evidence that the general somehow knew that he would win the lottery.

So, is it in fact true that psychology of the predicter plays no role in determining whether the fulfilment of the prediction is evidence that the predicter had access to information which allowed him to make an accurate prediction or influenced the events to make his prediction come true? Or am I right in thinking that sometimes – in particular, when we would expect the prediction to be made by the predictor despite its unlikelihood  - the fulfilment of the prediction seems to offer no significant evidence in favour of the predicter having some sort of foreknowledge (be it information we couldn’t access, some other source of knowledge or the ability to influence the relevant future events)?

Comment: "It has been claimed" where and by whom? Context can make a difference. When this is claimed, the prediction is most likely taken to be meant as a genuine prediction and not as wishful thinking, expression of resolve, fear mongering, or something else in disguise. In those cases, psychology obviously plays a role.

Comment: @A-LevelStudent If someone has been convicted several times of tampering with the lottery machine to win the prize, then we will suspect he did it again if he predicts that he is going to win the lottery again. Whether this would have something to do with the psychology of this person or something else would have to be decided by an expertise of the case.

Comment: We all have a shared interest in better understanding ourselves and understanding others. Experts are not always better. Pay attention to what outcomes you can and cannot predict or influence and then draw an inference to what you think another person might be able to predict or influence in some specific context. One story in the Bible the prophet tells a wicked king: Your blood will run in this field! Prophet later sends someone with oil to anoint Jehu King of Israel. When the battle is starts, a scout reports, "The riding is like Jehu in its fury." Jehu kills the wicked king as predicted!

Comment: In law school my friend had a roommate who would play poker at the casino on weekends. When we started playing poker every week, he told my friend, "I'm going to take Joe's money" (in the regular Tuesday night poker games). I would drink beer, have fun, and try to bluff randomly, intimidating this timid fool with my betting strategy and my devil-may-care attitude to the outcome of any particular hand of poker! He won some hands, I won some hands, but he never took my money! Poker is a game you play against the other players. Strategic interactions are called Game Theory.

Comment: A few years after graduating law school I play poker in a casino in Las Vegas. The drinks are free at the tables. I drink too much beer. I am too slow folding or deciding to take a card so two old ladies complain about this. I notice they fold frequently paying only the small ante to see their two hole cards. Later I wonder if these women are professional gamblers who use some conservative strategy to increase their odds of winning on average against beer drinking fools who have bad card reading skills and bet too aggressively!

Answer (score 2):

Consider a criminal with a long and consistent record of confidence tricks who wins an exceptional bet- would you consider their psychological disposition towards dishonesty and manipulation for criminal gain to be irrelevant when judging whether they had bet fairly? The answer to your question is clearly yes, it can be.

Comment: Thank for your answer. Would you also agree that the examples that I gave are alsoo valid examples which show that sometimes psychology is a factor as I thought?